# MVC and Object with Set<>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have 2 class which mapped in the Hibernate.
1. The class implements the account
2. The class implements the type of account.
**Important**! One account can have multiple types.

```
 Account.class
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "dp_account",
            uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id"})})
        public class Account {

            @Id
            @Column(name="id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private long id;

            @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
            private int price;

            @Column(name = "customer_id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
            private long customerId;

            @Column(name = "customer", length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
            private String customer;

            @Column(name = "comment", length = 1000)
            private String comment;

            @Column(name = "date", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
            @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
            private Date date;

            @Column(name = "is_deleted", nullable = false)
            private boolean deleted = false;

            @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = AccountType.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
            @JoinTable(name = "account_accountType",
                    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") },
                    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "type_id") })
            private Set<AccountType> accountTypes;
        // дальше конструкторы и геттеры/сеттеры
        }
```

The essence of the type of account that has the name, description, id and owner name.

```
    AccountType.class
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "account_type")
    public class AccountType {
        private static final Long serialVersionUID = -4727727495060874301L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "name", length = 25, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "description", length = 255)
        private String description;

        @Column(name = "user_login", length = 45, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String login;
   //дальше геттеры/сеттеры и конструкторы
}
```

The question is -  have a page where I fill out form to create account
(`Account.class`), i do `multiple select`, to fill types of accounts
(`AccountType.class`).  Account.class has field `Set<AccountType> accountTypes`, where each account contains a list of types. (This is the list I'm trying to fill, and then pass Account.class in MVC controller).But in controller I don't even get get 400 error. After numerous tests I realized that Spring MVC don't binddle my list. I would like to know how to do this?

MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/addAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addAccount(@ModelAttribute("accountAttribute") Account account) {
        System.out.println("Account on the top");
        System.out.println(account);
        ServiceFactory.getInstance().getAccountService().addAccount(account);
    }
```

JSP:

```
<div style="margin-top: 40px">
            <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/account/addAccount" method="post" modelAttribute="accountAttribute">

                <label>
                    Сумма: <input type="number" name="price">
                </label>
                <br> <br>

                <label>
                    Категория:
                    <select multiple name="accountTypes">
                        <c:forEach items="${accountTypes}" var="accountType">
                        <option value="${accountType.name}">${accountType.name}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <br><br>

                <label>Комментарий:
                    <br> <br>
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                </label>
                <br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Внести">

            </form:form>
        </div>
```

Screenshot example: 
[image: Скриншот]

UPDATE:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = (List<GrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String login = authentication.getName();
        if (grantedAuthorityList.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))) {
            model.setViewName("admin");
        } else {
            List<AccountType> accountTypes = ServiceFactory.getInstance().getAccountService().getAllAccountTypeByLogin(login);
            model.addObject("accountTypes", accountTypes);
            model.setViewName("user");
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the html select element but what you need to do is use spring tag library's select i.e:

```
<form:select path="accountTypes" multiple="true">
  <form:options items="${accountTypes}"/>
</form:select>
```

This way spring would bind the values in the controller.

Try using this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = (List<GrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String login = authentication.getName();
    if (grantedAuthorityList.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))) {
        model.setViewName("admin");
    } else {
        List<AccountType> accountTypes = ServiceFactory.getInstance().getAccountService().getAllAccountTypeByLogin(login);
        model.addObject("accountTypes", accountTypes);
        model.setViewName("user");
//Add here
model.addObject("accountAttribute", new Account());
    }
    return model;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but when i use your solution. I have a problem "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'accountAttribute' available as request attribute"

Comment: It is because probably you haven't added the  accountAttribute to the model in the controller, which returns ,the page that you have attached as screenshot.

Comment: Check in my Question post MVC controller. I think that i added accountAttribute. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The controller method that you have posted is mapped to the submit action of the page you attached, right?
whereas I am talking about the changes in the controller function that lands you to the form page.
Did you see my updated answer?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand what this controller is. I have a form which creates an object and what to do for this controller?

Comment: I understand, but before I get to the page, I can't add accountAttribute

Comment: Because the account is formed based on the shape

Comment: What you mean in this string? Account acc = service.getAccount();

Comment: It just means that you get the Account data from the db using service method.
 "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'accountAttribute' does this happen after you click the submit button, right?

Comment: right, why u unupdated your answer? do you have any ideas to solve?

Comment: what do you want me to add in block "add here"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106002/discussion-between-germansevostyanov-and-kuldeep-s-chauhan).

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, if interested can look at. I made a reply

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to register a property editor or converter which is capable of converting your account type names to the AccountType object. Your view send a string value for the accountTypes element. Spring needs to know how to bind the String value to the Object.

```
public class AccountTypeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

   public void setAsText(String text){
        AccountType accountType = // some logic to find account type by name
        setValue(accountType);
   }
}
```

In your controller you need an @InitBinder method to register your editor

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
   binder.registerCustomEditor(AccountType.class , new AccountTypeEditor());
}
```

}

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, if interested can look at. I made a reply

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem, I began to pass separately Set and separately the object itself Account. The problem was that I passed from jsp Account and i wanted to get Set, а this was not possible due to the fact I chose only **name** type account. This is solution my problem:

JSP:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/account/addAccount" method="post" modelAttribute="accountAttribute">

                <label>
                    Сумма: <input type="number" name="price">
                </label>
                <br> <br>

                <select multiple name="accountTypeNameSet" size="4s">
                    <c:forEach items="${accountTypes}" var="accountType">
                        <option >${accountType}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>

                <label>Комментарий:
                    <br> <br>
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                </label>
                <br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Внести">

            </form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/addAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addAccount(@ModelAttribute("accountAttribute") Account account, @RequestParam(value="accountTypeNameSet") Set<String> accountTypeNameSet) {
    // implementation here
// accountTypeNameSet - This is the list of names account type, which user selected. On the basis of these names we can pull your invoice from database.
```